# NestedScrollView into vertical ViewPager: scroll doesn't work properly

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-nestedscrollview

I have a vertical ViewPager. Each page contains some elements which a NestedScrollView. If I swipe outside of the NestedScrollView it works perfectly, but if I swipe inside the NestedScrollView the vertical scroll of ViewPager doesn't work.

My Nested:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingTop="6dp"
                android:paddingBottom="6dp"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:overScrollMode="never">
```

And I set the setup like that too:

```
scrollView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Could you help me guys? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Use `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent` so it will not allow child to intercept touch events.

```
yourViewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        yourViewPager.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return false;
    }
});
```

For more reference this [requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewParent#requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean))

Comment: Why getParent()? The NestedScrollView is inside the ViewPager and not the opposite